# Intellij cannot find .class

Tags: intellij-idea, .class-file

I got a little demo program with 2 `.class` files. If I want to open it in IntelliJ, my main class cannot find the other `.class` files. I already checked that all files are in the same folder.

[image: intellij cannot find symbol]

If I compile it with the Windows shell, everything works fine. Only IntelliJ can't find the files.

Comment: Could you hover with your mouse on the red light bulb (next to the code line marked in red) and add the text of the error here? This can help.

Comment: sure, I edited the image. thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue, I fixed by deleting this folder: %USER_HOME%\.IntelliJIdea70\system\caches - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206299399/comments/207234979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be due to the fact that your `FractalTerrain` file is not a *.java* file but it's a *.class* file.

You should move the *.class* files into target or make a *.java* file.

Comment: Oooh of course, thanks! Moving the .class files into the target ordner solved the problem. Strangely, the error messages didn't dissapear... but I guess it's a problem with intellij since compiling and running the main class now works fine